# Dark desktop theme with visible text fields

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I think we all like to change a theme for our Linux Desktops, for several years I have tried dozens of theme. I personally prefer dark themes. Unfortunately, many theme that looks nice at a first glance in a few hours show themselves as inconvenient for daily work. That is related to the facts, that some graphical elements in some application, or web pages are not or barely visible due to the colour scheme. I have found for me the best theme I like it is called Delorean theme. But even these wonderful theme is not without the same issue as others however at least in few cases. That filling forms on some websites I need to switch my theme to something basic, light to see the text field content.

Can somebody name me a dark theme that you have used for many months, or years, and that it does not have any problems at all with graphical elements?

Answer (score 3):

I use `arc-theme` since a long time ago and I am pretty happy with it.

**Dark version :**

[image]

[image]

**Darker version :**

[image]

### [image]

Here how you can install it:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arc-theme.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```

Comment: I do not see tooltips in my dolphin file manager ((. But theme is nice.

Comment: If you see small bugs like this, report them on [Arc Theme Github page](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme/issues). The author is quite reactive and can probably solve it quickly **;-)**.