# ASCII animations that are viewed in the command-line?

Tags: command-line, video, ascii, ascii-art

I like ASCII animations and want to view them through a terminal window.

What famous Linux programs and commands are suitable here to display ASCII animations or view videos in a terminal screen?

Comment: You mean animated ASCII art?

Comment: I'd like to clarify to the downvoters and thos who want to close this question - I meant ASCII animation - I didn't know what it was called :)

Comment: I retracted my close vote :)

Comment: I won't retract my vote since I view this as too broad.

Comment: Thanx for the edit @ByteCommander :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not really a short video but here is the most famous one: **Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope.**

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run :

```
telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```

[image]

Comment: what's your theme and terminal?

Comment: I am using [arc-theme](http://askubuntu.com/a/694640/338915) with Gnome terminal. Background color : #2F343F.

Answer (score 25):

You can play any video as an ascii animation with the caca video driver for mplayer:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer2 caca-utils
mplayer -vo caca /path/to/video
```

This has several output options which work better in X11 but can also work from a real terminal, even over SSH (urgh, it's horrible). It'll also sync sound in there too.

If you don't have any videos to hand, I can help you out.  You wouldn't get this from any other guy.  I just wanna tell you how I'm feeling. Gotta make you understand...

```
sudo wget -qO /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

youtube-dl -o- "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ" | mplayer -vo caca -
```

[image]

Comment: My eyes! My eyes!

Comment: The goggles do nothing.

Comment: Great one - but I have no more votes... :P Can it play sound too?

Comment: @ByteCommander: It is full MPlayer, so it supports all of MPlayer's audio output capabilities.

Comment: You do know that downloading YouTube videos violates the YouTube EULA?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Is it? I've just had a quick read and couldn't see anything against downloading user content. Plus Google tolerates a lot of applications that do just that in places it controls.

Comment: @oli https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms section 4 part c.

Comment: @CanadianLuke It seems like there is no way to execute this contract as a legal instrument unless you sign up for a youtube account and explicitly agree to the EULA. I'm sure most of it is to cover their butts to avoid the legal trouble of being defined as a "file sharing" website like Napster. Lots of video websites are not supported by youtube-dl and it seems like it should be alright so long as your intent is to watch the video and not obtain a file; your browser downloads a video every time you watch one.

Comment: @mchid I agree that they *likely* won't come after someone, but it's still possible. Personally, I err on the side of caution, and simply point it out to those two may not realize it, then leave it be (as you can see, this was over a year and a half ago).

Comment: Is there any way to save this to a video file so I can put it on my phone and watch it as I fall asleep each night?

Answer (score 17):

If you like trains, install `sl`:

```
sudo apt-get install sl
```

[image]

Now you can enjoy a beautiful old steam locomotive driving through your terminal as often as you want!

Also try `sl` with different parameters:

- `-a`: "accident" - people in the train crying for help
- `-l`: "little" - a smaller locomotive
- `-F`: "flying" - antigravity is cool! ;D

Comment: I'm thoroughly convinced there should be a `car`executable to be run when you misspell `cat`.

Comment: @kos that would be *so* cool  :)

Comment: The joke is that you get a train every time you make typo of `ls` ;)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - sadly it does not have the screensaver behavior like `cmatrix`, in the `man sl` there is no indication

Answer (score 17):

Try this command:

```
$ curl -s http://artscene.textfiles.com/vt100/movglobe.vt | pv -q -L 9600
```

to see animated AsciiGlobe:

[image]

More examples: http://artscene.textfiles.com/vt100/

What is Animated Ascii Art?: http://www.qqpr.com/ascii-art-article-2.html

Source of command line snippet: http://www.cambus.net/visualizing-progression-of-file-operations-using-pv-pipe-viewer/

Comment: This should have been the accepted answere.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install pv` to install `pv`

Answer (score 12):

This is also a great one - I haven't tried it but it looks awesome...

#### A live aquarium!

[image]

You can find out how to install it [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/03/02/have-some-linux-ascii-fun-with-asciiquarium/).

Answer (score 9):

I've just found one:

**Burn your terminal:**

```
sudo apt-get install libaa-bin
```

Run it with `aafire`:

[image]

Comment: hey that's neat

Comment: Wow, animated fractals in ascii is hard to beat!

Answer (score 9):

What 6 answers and no mention of bb?

Youtube vid at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ukhOAUseKY

[image]

if not installed:

```
sudo apt-get install bb
```

run with:

```
bb
```

Comment: I just watched the YouTube video you linked, but **COOL!** :D